Microsoft Graph Search api not returning hits for past events where I am an attendee
I am using the graph search API to search for past events based on user's keyword search.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/microsoft.graph.query
Here is an example of the query I am sending in the request body:
{
    "Requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "event"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "libra"
            }
        }
    ]
}

When I am searching for events where I am the organizer, it returns correct hits even with partial keywords.
But for meetings where I am an attendee, the results do not return proper results even when I am searching with the exact meeting subject. Around 10% of the time, I do get results, but it is not consistent.
I tried the same in Graph explorer with the same results.
I have granted Calendar.Read scope access.
